# Php and Mysqli how to echo break of line

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi guys when I save with php some part of text (with break of lines) for example:

```
this is 

an example
```

in my database I see like I wrote it

[image]

But when I echo this data from my database I see it wrong

[image]

Can you help me?

My code is this

```
echo '<p class="date">' . $date . "</p>";
echo '<p class="post">' . $posts . "</p>";
```

Comment: What is wrong with the display? Looks OK from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check nl2br function (http://php.net/nl2br)

```
echo '<p class="date">' . $date . "</p>";
echo '<p class="post">' . nl2br($posts) . "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HTML doesn't break line with newline character.
PHP provides a function that converts newlines to `<BR>` tags.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp