# Preserve line breaks in mysqli fetch_assoc( ) PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get all the rows from my MySQL database using the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $output[]=$row;
    }
echo json_encode($output);
```

My question is, How to preserve the line breaks using this code? I can preserve line breaks using nl2br() when I need a particular string for example

```
nl2br($_row['fieldName']);
```

but I want to know How can I use the same nl2br() when fetching the result in an array?

I have referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626470/php-and-mysqli-how-to-echo-break-of-line) as well but this explains just for a single string not the array.

If there is no way of doing it, please suggest me some other way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `array_map` you can call the function, so with the value of each `$row` you can get the values.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $output[]=array_map("nl2br",$row);
     }
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to know exactly what kind of text flow your json must send. Using php's nl2br function will insert a HTML tag named "br" before newlines used for displaying linebreaks when a browser render HTML. If the application that you feed with this json flow is expecting plain text and not HTML, using nl2br is not the right solution. In this case, I suggest to replace newlines with an escaped sequence as "\n" in your string before sending it as a parameter to the json_encode function, and to handle the decoding in your json flow consumer code adequately regarding what you want to do with it, html or anything else.
In this case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587496/output-line-breaks-or-new-lines-with-json-encode) may help.

Comment: This is a misleading answer.  From the PHP manual: **Returns string with <br /> or <br> inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).**